# How to run a simple class file from Linux shell?

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I want to run a simple java file on my Linux host.

I started with a simple shell command:

```
mkdir -p ~/py4j/examples
```

I put AdditionApplication.java in the above folder

The file looks like this:

```
// ~/py4j/examples/AdditionApplication.java

package py4j.examples;

import py4j.GatewayServer;

public class AdditionApplication {

  public int addition(int first, int second) {
    return first + second;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AdditionApplication app = new AdditionApplication();
    // app is now the gateway.entry_point
    GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(app);
    server.start();
  }
}
```

Notice that it imports this:

```
import py4j.GatewayServer;
```

The above import depends on code here:

```
~/py4j0.10.6.jar
```

Next I installed java and set two env variables:

```
export JAVA_HOME=${HOME}/jdk
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```

I use this shell command to see it:

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -version
```

It says:

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

Next I ran two shell commands:

```
cd ~
javac -cp py4j0.10.6.jar py4j/examples/AdditionApplication.java
```

The above command created a class file:

```
dan@h79:~ $ ll py4j/examples/AdditionApplication.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dan dan 472 Dec 22 20:59 py4j/examples/AdditionApplication.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dan dan 431 Dec 22 20:58 py4j/examples/AdditionApplication.java
dan@h79:~ $
```

Next I ran another shell command:

```
dan@h79:~ $ java -cp py4j0.10.6.jar py4j.examples.AdditionApplication
Error: Could not find or load main class py4j.examples.AdditionApplication
dan@h79:~ $
```

Question: How do I run ~/py4j/examples/AdditionApplication.class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add classpath for `AdditionApplication` as well.

```
java -cp py4j0.10.6.jar:. py4j.examples.AdditionApplication
```

Notice the `:.`. `:` is path separator, `.` is current directory. Of course that assumes current folder is `~`,

Comment: :. works well. SOF is broken tho; I cant accept the answer.Thanks!

Comment: try refreshing :)